# Working on mac but not on machine - linux ubuntu - node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, macos

I've got problem with my http server, here is code:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;


const request = require('request');


var dpi = "half api code type 1"; 
var ipn = "half api code type 2"; 
var close = "2nd half api code ";



var ipnTable = ['table with links'];


var dpiTable = ['table with links',];





request(dpi+dpiTable[0]+close { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body.url);
  console.log(body.explanation);
});



  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    } 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080, 'ip / hostname of my machine - idk what to chose');
```

It's working on mac but i'm receiving some error on machine, look at this:

```
0|serwer2  |     at Server.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/smcheck/serwer2.js:10:17)
0|serwer2  |     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
0|serwer2  |     at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
0|serwer2  |     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
0|serwer2  |     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
0|serwer2  | Error: Cannot find module 'request'
0|serwer2  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
0|serwer2  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
0|serwer2  |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
0|serwer2  |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
0|serwer2  |     at Server.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/smcheck/serwer2.js:10:17)
0|serwer2  |     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
0|serwer2  |     at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
0|serwer2  |     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
```

Please, help me guys, I don't have any idea what to do...

I'm trying to send request to the api of one website, on mac I'm receiving undefined responses - probably because the api server is using revdns for authentication.

The question is, why I've got all the time this same problem and if u have any idea how to put response from the api server into some div it would be nice.

Thanks, beer for all who's interested in.

Comment: did you run `npm install` ?

Comment: yes, i used this

Comment: `request` is not a built-in module. You have to install it first.

Comment: Okay, I used npm install request -g and problem is still the same... Maybe npm is not doing it well or something?

Comment: Okay, there is probably problem with machine, I'll check it out and give answer,

Comment: Npm should produce a package lock file when you npm install — is this lock file the same on both machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot require globally installed npm modules by default

Instead of `npm install request -g` do `npm install request --save`

It's working on your Mac probably because there is a NODE_PATH environment variable pointing to global `node_modules` directory. In Linux, you can do this by: `export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules` (path could be different on your machine)

Comment: npm install request --save solved problem. Many thanks!!